# Power BI Embedded - Error while opening the report - Failed to load settings

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have embedded the Power BI Report. On clicking the report, it gives the below error.
[image]

On clicking the close button , the report loads fine but still i get this error.

Comment: I am receiving the same thing.  I have a ticket open with Microsoft, from what I am told they are aware and working to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: Just received an email about my ticket and was told to follow the status here: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/support/

Comment: Just informed that this is resolved now.